# How to filter records by date with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a filter like this

[image: filter]

I have a working date filter with laravel. The problem is that if I don't filter my records when no records are shown.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $stats = [
        'done' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['done'])->count(),
        'canceled' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['canceled'])->count(),
        'all' => UserTransaction::count(),
    ];
    if ($request->start_date && $request->end_date){
        $dateS = new Carbon($request->start_date);
        $dateE = new Carbon($request->end_date);
        $result = UserTransaction::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateS->format('Y-m-d'), $dateE->format('Y-m-d')])->get();
    }
    if ($request->search) {
        $transactions = UserTransaction::search($request->search)->paginate(5);
    } else {
        $transactions = UserTransaction::paginate(5);
    }
    if ($transactions->count() == 0 && $request->search ) {
        msg()->warning('No records found');
    }
    return view('transaction::admin.index', compact('transactions', 'stats', 'result'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider changing your logic a little to allow for people to specify either just a `start date` or just an `end date` which could be entirely possible from a usability perspective.

Create a query builder, then add `where` clauses for the `start_date` and `end_date` if they appear in your `$request` object. If they do not appear then you can use the query as you have been doing so already.

```php
$transactions = Transaction::query();

if ($request->start_date) {
  $query->whereDate('start_date', '>=', new Carbon($request->start_date));
}

if ($request->end_date) {
  $query->whereDate('end_date', '<=', new Carbon($request->end_date));
}

if ($requer->search) {
  $query->search($request->search);
}

$query->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if condition inside query and remove outer if condition

```
$result = UserTransaction::where(function($query)use($request){
    if(!empty($request->start_date)&&!empty($request->end_date)){
    
      $dateS = new Carbon($request->start_date);
      $dateE = new Carbon($request->end_date);
      $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$dateS->format('Y-m-d'), $dateE->format('Y-m-d')]);
    }
    })->get();
```